# Align a div to the center and then move it left

Tags: css, html, alignment, center, pixel

I am using the following code to make a div...

```
left:50%; 
top:0px;
width:100%; 
margin-left:-50%;

background:black;

padding:20px;

position:fixed;
```

But the problem is there is a padding on the div so I need to add in an extra 20px to align the div to center. Is there a way to do this? I tried something like `margin-left:-(50%+20px);` but that doesn't work in CSS...

Anyone know how I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**box-sizing** would work, but unfortunately it doesn't work on older browsers (ie7 and older).
http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing

The best thing to do (*if targeting all browsers*) is to remove the padding and add a child wrapper with only that padding.

html:

```
<div id="centered">
  <div id="wrapper">
    [...]
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Not a bad idea but it is more complicated.. And who uses internet explorer? ;) However, +1 for a different response.

Comment: The good thing is that not many people use IE7 and less. The bad thing is that you often come across a specific client that requests cross-browser compatability and demads ie7 or even ie6 to be on that list. That will make your job a lot harder.

Comment: I might as well go the hard route and do this. :)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

So includes padding in calculation of width;
Cheers
See rec : http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0

Comment: What do I replace with this?

Comment: Include it in your rules ,the box will be:  width:100% with inside padding and not 100% + padding.